# Открытие поисковика в новой вкладке

Tags: html

Как сделать так, чтобы на сайте при активации поисковика, человека перекидывало на новую вкладку, а на старой вкладке, где он вписывал запрос в форме для поисковика, было чисто, то есть если я пишу в поисковике "Новости", меня перекидывает на новую вкладку, а там где я писал Новости, ничего не было? Вот примерный код для поисковика:

```
<div class="topbar-search"><form action="http://ru.wowhead.com/search" target="_blank"><input name="q" value="" autocomplete="off"></form><a href="javascript:;"></a></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<input id="search" />
<a href="#" onClick="window.open('http://yandex.ru/yandsearch?text='+getElementById('search').value); return false;">Find me</a>
```